# how to do simple jquery for multiple actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make simple jquery that can function for many objects by Id .

For example If i have this HTML :

```
<div id="all-ids">
   <div id="parent-id-1">
      <div id="1">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parent-id-2">
      <div id="2">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="parent-id-3">
      <div id="3">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

now if i need to do a click function for this i would do like this :

```
$(document).on("click","#parent-id-1",function() {
   $('#1').show();
});

$(document).on("click","#parent-id-2",function() {
   $('#2').show();
});

$(document).on("click","#parent-id-3",function() {
   $('#3').show();
});
```

is there in way to make the above Jquery something more simpler since i have to many divs ? ... i mean something like this :

```
$(document).on("click","#parent-id-|ID-NUMBER|",function() {
   $('#|ID-NUMBER|').show();
});
```

so this code would work for even 1000 id.

**NOTE:The |ID-NUMBER| are both the in #parent-id and just the #id.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use IDs, is very complex and not scalable. Use classes instead:

```
<div id="all-ids">
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="children">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="children">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="children">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

In jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click",".parent",function() {
   $(this).find('.children').show();
});
```

You don't need more and you can write millions of parents and its children.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(index) {
  $(document).on("click","#parent-id-" + index,function() {
     $('#' + index).show();
  });
});
```

or alternatively, if you don't want to name both divs, you can either use `>` to point the direct child of a parent `div`, or write another selector. To achieve that you can do:

```
<div id="all-ids">
   <div class="parent">
      <div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

and in javascript:

```
$(document).on("click",".parent",function() {
   $(this).find('>div').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different selector. I think you actually want to click on the Element and not the body. I'm thinking this is what you want:

```
$('[id^=parent-id]').each(function(i, e){
  var el = $(e);
  el.click(function(){
    el.children(':first').show();
  });
});
```

Note that you cannot start an HTML attribute or JavaScript variable with a number, including an id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector to select elements that have an id value that starts with 'parent-id-'.

```js
$(document).on("click", "[id^=parent-id-]", function(e) {
  alert($(this).attr("id").replace("parent-id-", ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all-ids">
  <div id="parent-id-1">
    <div id="1">
      <div>Lorem</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent-id-2">
    <div id="2">
      <div>Ipsum</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent-id-3">
    <div id="3">
      <div>Dolor</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```